# Bootstrap Input fields aren't centering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="radio" name="measurement" value="far" checked="checked" /> F
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="measurement" value="cel" /> C
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure why it's left-aligned. I thought the `text-center` class center aligned anything? And since it's within a div that is `col-xs-12`, doesn't that make it center-aligned? Or what am I missing?

Comment: `.btn` elements in a `.btn-group` are floated to the left and are not inline elements so `.text-center` will have no affect on them. `.col-xs-12` tells the element what percentage width to have of the parent `.row` element. `.col-xs-12` has nothing to do with centering.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is the btn-group. You need to move it to a div under the text-center. The code will look like;

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" data-toggle="buttons">
             <div class="btn-group">
                 <label class="btn btn-primary active">
                     <input type="radio" name="measurement" value="far" 
                     checked="checked" /> F
                 </label>
                 <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="measurement" value="cel" /> C
                 </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```